# TypeScript errors with JSX syntax but not with function syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I created a new create-react-app project and added one file to it. My component compiles fine if I try to use it using function syntax. But if I try to use it with JSX syntax I get a TypeScript type error; **type narrowing** isn't happening **in the JSX**. Is there some way for me to use this component with JSX syntax?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lamarr-dex8o5?file=/src/App.tsx

```
type JSXElement = JSX.Element;

function ShowType<A, B extends A>(props: {
  value: A;
  isB: (a: A) => NonNullable<B> | undefined;
  asB: (i: NonNullable<B>) => JSXElement;
  fallback: JSXElement;
}) {
  return props.isB(props.value)
    ? props.asB(props.isB(props.value)!)
    : props.fallback;
}

type User =
  | { tag: "anonymous" }
  | { tag: "signedIn"; userName: string; avatar: string };

// Type checks and works fine on my computer and gives proper auto-complete for
// the asB function my computer
const Greeting1 = (s: User) =>
  ShowType({
    value: s,
    isB: (i) => (i.tag === "signedIn" ? i : undefined),
    asB: (b) => <div>Hi, ${b.userName}</div>,
    fallback: <div>Hello, stranger!</div>,
  });

// TypeScript error
const Greeting2 = (s: User) => (
  <ShowType
    value={s}
    isB={(i) => (i.tag === "signedIn" ? i : undefined)}
    asB={(b) => <div>Hi, ${b.userName}</div>}
    fallback={<div>Hello, stranger!</div>}
  />
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `User type` is problematic. If you define a clearer interface using optional `?` flags, the issue goes away.

Instead of using:

```js
type User =
  | { tag: "anonymous" }
  | { tag: "signedIn"; userName: string; avatar: string };
```

Use this instead:

```js
interface User {
  tag: 'anonymous' | 'signedIn';
  userName?: string;
  avatar?: string;
}
```

I do not recommend just casting a variable as another type to hide the issue - because then you don't actually identify what's wrong. Tuple types work but not in this way.

Here's a working sandbox of your code using this interface:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-torvalds-61hivb

I hope this helps!

Comment: The type definition is just fine. This is a simpler example of a "discriminated union" from functional programming. I want to distinguish which type the object is and then have 2 type-safe functions - no casting - to display views of those choices. With your solution userName is always string | undefined in both paths; once I know someone is a user I want TypeScript to know that userName is string.